# Expose method's source code through reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

Several answers here on Stack Overflow says, that it is not possible to get the source code out of .NET assembly using regular reflection, that I can only access the IL code.

In my project a third party will write some elementary C# code into a project template created by me and build a .NET dll. I need to pull out some information out of those dlls. To collect some of the information the dll has to be invoked - and I will use reflection to that. Unfortunately I also need to get a source code of one particular method.

I could parse the cs file - it wouldn't be a big problem, but I was wondering. Since I have to already use reflection and the project template is completely under my control, can I do something to intentionally expose a part of the source code (Maybe somehow build it in compile time to resources or something equally wacky)?

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how well it might work for your purposes, but http://ilspy.net/ has an open source IL decompiler.

Comment: This is an extremely lossy proposition.  Work with the 3rd party to get them to provide you with the info you need.  A simple [attribute] can do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned something wacky, you could technically just expose a property that is just the text of the method. That way you can use reflection to get the property value.  It could be a ready only property that returns a constant. It just is a pain to maintain if the method were to ever change since you'd have to change it in two places.

Another equally wacky way to handle this, and it's related to above, is to just use the string property you create above to act as the method text.  Then in your actual class where you would have had the method, you could dynamically take the text, build it on the fly, and execute it. This solves the problem of changing it in two places.  However, this is probably a performance nightmare, but it seems like it would be possible.

Here's a couple of sample articles out there on how to compile and execute dynamic code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5472/Compiling-NET-code-on-the-fly

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamiccode/dynamiccode.htm